# Update Statement in Oracle using inner join? (copying data from table1.column1 to table2.column1)

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

This is what I have tried so far (Oracle SQL):

```
UPDATE table1
   SET table1.ADDRESS =
          (SELECT table2.ADDRESS
             FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
            WHERE     table1.ADDRESS <> table2.ADDRESS
                  AND table1.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('9999-12-31')
                                         AND TO_DATE ('9999-01-21'));
```

(The dates I picked are random)

> Getting ORA-1427 Error - single-row subquery returns more than one
>   row..

Comment: Pls give us sample data for all tables and expected result.

Comment: `INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
        WHERE table1.column1 <> table2.column1`  - Are you sure?

Comment: Query, as it is, doesn't make sense. You are joining tables on COLUMN1, and then - in the WHERE condition - say that they are different. I suspect that the JOIN condition should be modified. Anyway, some more info could help. Also, dates - although randomly picked - are invalid. First of all, use DATE literals (or TO_DATE function, with appropriate format mask). Furthermore, nothing is between 31.12.9999 and 21.01.9999 (that's *backwards*).

Comment: Your subquery will never return row INNER JOIN and WHERE clause with <> in the same columns. Have you changed the query to post ?. Whats is the primary key for both table ? you may  need to change the ON to match the primary key

Comment: Please don't deface your questions. If you wish to remove it, use the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your subquery

```
SELECT table2.column1 
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1 
WHERE table1.column1 <> table2.column1 
AND table1.column2 BETWEEN TO-DATE('9999-12-31') AND TO_DATE(9999-01-21)
```

returns more than one row (as the error text states). You have either have to add a `WHERE ROWNUM <= 1` or some other condition to reduce the selected rows to exactly one.

Answer (score 0):

Plain `UPDATE`:

```
update table1
set    table1.address =
       ( select table2.address
         from   table2
         where  table2.id = table1.id
         and    table2.address <> table1.address )
where  table1.date between date '9999-01-21' and date '9999-12-31'
and    exists
       ( select 1
         from   table2
         where  table2.id = table1.id
         and    table2.address <> table1.address );
```

Updateable inline view (requires a unique index or constraint on `table2.id`):

```
update ( select t1.address as old_address, t2.address as new_address
         from   table1 t1
                join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
         where  t2.address <> t.address
         and    t1.date between date '9999-01-21' and date '9999-12-31' )
set old_address = new_address;
```

Update-only `MERGE`:

```
merge into table1 t1
using table2 t2
on    (      t2.id = t1.id
        and  t2.address <> t.address 
        and  t1.date between date '9999-01-21' and date '9999-12-31' )
when  matched then update set t1.address = t2.address;
```

Answer (score -2):

You used `= operator` instead of `IN`. `IN accept multiple values` where as `= accepts single value.`

Your query returns more than one values.

Comment: Can you provide an example of using the IN keyword.. as I don't see a viable spot that would actually work in this case..

Comment: This will work. UPDATE table1
   SET table1.column1 in
          (SELECT table2.column1
             FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
            WHERE     table1.column1 <> table2.column1
                  AND table1.column2 BETWEEN TO_DATE ('9999-12-31')
                                         AND TO_DATE ('9999-01-21'));

Comment: Cannot use IN keyword after SET in an oracle environment gives "SQL Error: ORA-00927: missing equal sign"